# Cannot delete pdf due to lock on the document C#

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, itext

I have a situation where I replicate a pdf from an existing pdf blank 'certificate', The replica pdf contains some personal info that was added to the 'blue print' copy.

After mailing this to the user I want to delete it again so as not to save a copy on the server.

No matter what I do, however, I get the error message

```
The process cannot access the file 'certificate#672712.pdf' because it is being used by another process.
```

It is pretty clear what the message means, what I want to know is how I should alter the code for the certificate creation part so that is 'released' after words.

This is the code that I use.

```
try
{
    string suffix =  (DateTime.Now.Day % 10 == 1 && DateTime.Now.Day != 11) ? "st of"
                    : (DateTime.Now.Day % 10 == 2 && DateTime.Now.Day != 12) ? "nd of"
                    : (DateTime.Now.Day % 10 == 3 && DateTime.Now.Day != 13) ? "rd of"
                    : "th of";
    string dateToday = string.Format("{0:dd}{1} {0:MMMM yyyy}", DateTime.Now, (suffix));
    Random generator = new Random();
    string referenceNumber = "#" + generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
    string bluePrint = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/blue_print.pdf");
    if (certificateNumber != "")
    {
        referenceNumber = certificateNumber;
    }
    string certificate = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/certificate_" + referenceNumber + ".pdf");
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bluePrint); 
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(certificate, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        reader.SelectPages("1");
        var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);


        PdfContentByte pbover = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        pbover.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
        Font font = new Font(bf);
        font.Size = 32;

        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pbover, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(UserName, font), 90, 305, 0);
    }
    reader.Close();              
    return referenceNumber;
}
catch (Exception exe)
{
    return exe.Message.ToString();
}
```

in my controller method I call the methods in this sequence.

```
//certificate
    var reference = UtilityService.GenerateCertificate(String.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName), "");
    //Mail the certificate
    string message = await MailService.MailTheCertificate(user.Email, "Well done", "Well done on completing the course", reference);

    //THE ERROR HAPPENS AS I AM TRYING TO DELETE THE CERTIFICATE
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/certificate_" + reference + ".pdf"));

    file.Delete();
    return Ok("success");
```

Comment: Did you make sure `MailService` does not have any reference to the document (i.e. the file) after `MailTheCertificate` is done? That means all streams are close, disposed, etc... FileInfo's are disposed/nulled ...

Comment: Why on earth would you first create the file on disk, then use it, then delete it? Why don't you create the file in memory, use it, and just release the memory. This will be much faster and you won't have the problem of a file being locked by some external process.

Comment: I ran your example and I could delete the file, so probably the problem is in MailService.MailTheCertificate

Comment: Cool, thanks allot for the advice. It is a bit silly creating the certificate on disk I realise

Comment: It was indeed the MailMessage that locked the file. `using(MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()){}` solved it :-)

Comment: As an aside, you manipulate the `PdfReader` (doing `reader.SelectPages("1")`) *after* starting to stamp it. If I were you, I'd do all `PdfReader` manipulations *before* starting to stamp it.